# varnish depending on the response body avoid caching

Tags: varnish

does any one know if it is possible on vanish to avoid caching if there are some "keywords" in the response body? I need something like this:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (beresp.body ~ "the string to search for") {
        return (pass);
    }
}
```

does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like any version of Varnish supports access for `beresp.body` from within `vcl_backend_response`. If it would, then something like this would suffice:

```cpp
sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (beresp.body ~ "the string to search for") {
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    } 
}
```

At present this is not possible unless you write a VMOD.